# Changing Display Language in Windows 10 does not reflect in CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, localization, windows-10, cultureinfo

I changed the default language in my windows 10 (enterprise/pro) system using the 'Region & Language' settings and set french as the default language.  Many of the application in windows is now showing its UI in french, but my .Net application is still using the English strings (even though I have fr-FR satellite assemblies).
(Note: Windows was installed with en-US as the language).

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` return the following information:

Default Language Info:

* Name: en-US

* Display Name: English (United States)

* English Name: English (United States)

* 2-letter ISO Name: en

* 3-letter ISO Name: Eng

* 3-letter Win32 API Name: ENU

CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture properties also return the same.

Why is the system language change not reflected by .Net? Am I missing something?